# Unable to install plugin in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm running Windows 7 32 bit. I just installed Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.1. I set up my rails sample application and everything seems to be working fine. I tried installing the `restful_authentication` plugin from github and it's been a nightmare. I'm executing the following command:

```
rails plugin install -force git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git
```

...and i get the get the following error:

```
Cannot install using checkout because this project is not under subversion.
```

How do i get around this? I've installed both the SVN and Git command-line clients and they're in my PATH.

Comment: restful-authentication is not a good choice with Rails 3.0.1 It's even not compatible like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you should not use this plugin with Rails 3. Use devise.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a linux or a mac for Rails development.
2. According to the [installation notes](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/wiki#INSTALL) you need to simply clone the project to the plugins dir.

   git clone git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
3. As others have suggested, [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a better option.